# Is sound registered as weight by a scale?

Tags: waves, momentum, acoustics

Okay, weird question.  I know a sound wave is energy and energy has a mass equivalent, but this question is about weight not mass, or at least as it is read by a scale.  Assume that a loud sound is directed towards the pan of a weighing scale, would this press down on the pan and produce a weight reading?  How can this weight be calculated based on the sound?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're asking if a sound wave carries momentum. That is, if a sound wave has a momentum flux  then when it reflects off the pan there will be a change in the momentum flux of 2. Since the force is d/dt this will produce a force on the balance of 2. Is this a fair interpretation of your question?

Comment: Yes.  Also I am concerned with the average weight being positive and it's possible the sound wave will bounce the pan up and down averaging zero weight.  This is not what I would consider to be weight for the purpose of this question.

Comment: We can hear sounds because the sound waves 'press up and down' on our ear drums.

Comment: Clickbait title (though please don’t): “how much does heavy metal music weigh?”

Comment: A sound wave striking the pan of a weighing scale would apply an _alternating_ force to the pan: first pushing, then pulling, and alternating at the frequency of the wave. If the scale were able to measure the weight fast enough to record those variations in pressure, then we could call the scale by another name. We could call it a _microphone_ because that is exactly what a microphone does. It measures fluctuations in the pressure that its diaphragm feels in the presence of a sound wave.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You can say the same thing about water waves at the beach: sometimes pushing, sometimes pulling. But waves at the beach carry real linear momentum, which can be extracted by surfers.

Comment: @rob, Breaking "waves" on the beach aren't really _waves_ anymore. They obey a different law from waves in deep water, sound waves, light waves, etc. But of course, the energy in those breakers that propels the surfer was transmitted from distant parts by the deep water waves.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Deep-water waves also carry momentum and can be “surfed.” There’s a fun, long, pub-level discussion to be had about examples, dispersion, solitons, etc. which isn’t really relevant to this question. Perhaps I’ll construct a follow-up question.

Answer (score 3):

A sound wave does indeed carry momentum, so if a sound wave reflects off a surface, or is absorbed by a surface it will exert a force on that surface. This is the same principle by which [light exerts a pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure).

Calculating the momentum of a sound wave is somewhat involved, but there is a shortcut we can use as for many types of wave the momentum flux is related to the energy flux by:

$$ p = \frac E v $$

where $v$ is the phase velocity. Since sound waves are (almost) non-dispersive the phase velocity is just *the speed of sound*. The energy flux is fairly straightforward to calculate. [LibreTexts has a nice derivation](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Introductory_Physics_-_Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World_(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/14%3A_Waves/14.05%3A_Energy_Transported_by_a_Wave) or the derivation was asked about here in [Relation between Displacement Amplitude and Intensity of Sound Waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645020/relation-between-displacement-amplitude-and-intensity-of-sound-waves). I'd have thought you would find similar derivations in most mechanics books. The result is:

$$ E = \tfrac12 \rho\omega^2a^2v $$

where $E$ is the power per square metre, $\rho$ is the density of the gas, $a$ is the amplitude of the sound wave and $\omega$ is the angular frequency. Dividing by the sound velocity gives us the momentum flux:

$$ p = \tfrac12 \rho\omega^2a^2 $$

If the pan on your balance has an area $A$ then the force the balance measures is somewhere between $Ap$ and $2Ap$ depending on how much of the sound wave is absorbed and how much is reflected.

Comment: Is the amplitude $a$ in units of pressure? It would be interesting estimate these momentum densities for a few sound levels in decibels, which are more familiar to most people.

Comment: @rob no, $a$ is the maximum displacement of the gas molecules from their equilibrium position. So just feed in the gas density and displacement in SI and you'll get the momentum flux. I have an idea there has already been a question hereabouts that asked about relating to displacement to the sound intensity ...

Answer (score 2):

Sound "wave momentum" is an ill-defined concept. There is also  more that one way to define and observe the pressure exerted by a sound wave 1) Langevin Radiation Pressure 2) The Rayleigh definition.  A good source is the delightfully polemical  [On the Wave Momentum Myth](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Michael-Mcintyre-2/publication/256198536_On_the_%27wave_momentum%27_myth/links/5512f2c50cf232031999cf60/On-the-wave-momentum-myth.pdf) by Michael McIntyre (scroll down the page to the actual article when you click the link) and also a  [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0012316) that I wrote on the topic.