# Derivation of intensity of a sound wave (missing calculation in the book)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, integration, intensity

The question is about a calculation in the first section of this page: https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/17-3-sound-intensity

Essentially, it states: "To find the time-averaged intensity over one period $T=2\pi/\omega$ for a position $x$, we integrate over the period" and they present the result:$$\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}[\beta k \omega s_\text{max}^2\sin^2(kx-\omega t+\phi)]dt=\frac{\beta k\omega s_\text{max}^2}{2}$$

I am having trouble coming to the same conclusion. This is my calculation so far:$$\begin{align*}\beta k \omega s_\text{max}^2\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}\sin^2(kx-\omega t+\phi)dt=\beta k \omega s_\text{max}^2\int_0^{2\pi/\omega}(\frac12-\frac12\cos[2(kx-\omega t+\phi)])dt\end{align*}$$

Now, my evaluation of the integral, using $u=2(kx-\omega t+\phi)$, results in$$\beta k \omega s_\text{max}^2\left[-\frac u{4\omega}+\frac{\sin(u)}{4\omega}\right]|_0^{2\pi/\omega}=\beta k \omega s_\text{max}^2\left[-\frac {2kx-2\omega t+2\phi}{4\omega}+\frac{\sin(2kx-2\omega t+2\phi)}{4\omega}\right]|_0^{2\pi/\omega}=\beta k\omega s_\text{max}^2\left[\left(\frac{-2kx+4\pi-2\phi+\sin\left(2kx-4\pi+2\phi\right)}{4\omega}\right)+\left(\frac{2kx+2\phi-\sin\left(2kx+2\phi\right)}{4\omega}\right)\right]=\beta ks_\text{max}^2\pi$$

This does not look like the correct solution so where did I take the wrong turn? Also, I had to assume that $\sin(2kx-4\pi+2\phi)$ and $\sin(2kx+2\phi)$ subtract to zero (since it represents the same function but phase shifted?)

The answer to this question ([Relation between Displacement Amplitude and Intensity of Sound Waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645020/relation-between-displacement-amplitude-and-intensity-of-sound-waves)) looks very similar to my calculation but the book I mentioned, first does not explain how it got there and second, results in a different final expression of intensity at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time-averaged intensity is the integral of intensity over a period, *divided by the period*. You have done the integral correctly, but have not divided by the period $2\pi/\omega$.